# What is the difference between $v=fλ$ and maximum velocity in the formula $v=ωY_{\max}$?

Tags: optics, waves, velocity, frequency, wavelength

I was wondering what the difference is between speed in the formula $v=fλ$ and maximum velocity in the formula $v=ωY_{\max}$ as applied to a wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v=f\lambda$ refers to the relationship between the speed of a wave that is travelling through a medium to its frequency and wavelength.

Now, forget the waves and come to *oscillations* for example like the simple pendulum.

The position of the Bob is $x=x_0 sin(\omega t+ \phi)$ . If you differentiate this with respect to time, we get

$\dot x = \omega x_0 cos( \omega t + \phi)$
This is the formula of the velocity of the bob whose amplitude is given by

$\dot x_{max} = v_{max}= \omega x_0$, which is what you wanted.

You got confused between waves and oscillations.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, that's really helpful!